# Can "fair enough" mean "quantity enough"?

Tags: meaning

The adjective *fair* can mean quite large/big or many in quantity or degree.

Can "fair enough" mean "It's quite big enough" or "It's quite much/many enough"?

Answer (score 3):

No. [*Fair enough*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fair+enough) is a set expression meaning that something is reasonable/all right.

One could come up with a sentence like

> You proposed a split of the treasure which isn't fair enough.

but 'fair' still carries the meaning of 'reasonable', and not 'quite large'.

Comment: Thank you for answering a very old question. Happy New Year!

Comment: Thank you, so is there an expression for something or sometimes it's much/many/big enough?

Comment: Maybe *sufficient*?

Comment: Hm... it's ok but like some phrases maybe?

Comment: That sounds like a *new* question. Be sure to read what's required for a good [phrase request](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info), or your question might get closed.